# Unicode symbol is not displaying in tooltip in chrome (43) or IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, unicode, character-encoding, symbols

I have an anchor tag title that contains the glyph symbol "☀", however when I place my cursor over the anchor to display the tooltip it displays a square instead of the symbol.

I'm only having this problem in IE and Chrome 43. This seems to work fine in Firefox and Chrome 45.

Here's the code:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="active elipsisforleftnav" id="csl_1" title="☀">☀</a>
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="active elipsisforleftnav" id="csl_{{subject.id}}" ng-click="subjectLinePopUp(subject)" title="{{subject.subject}}">{{subject.subject}}

Comment: here subject is replaced with "☀ Test" this is fine, but toll tip is not showing properly

Comment: I'm assuming `{{subject.subject}}` returns ☀?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get Unicode characters to display properly for the tooltip for the IMG ALT in IE7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11690/how-can-i-get-unicode-characters-to-display-properly-for-the-tooltip-for-the-img)

Answer (score 0):

Browsers typically handle tooltips by passing them to the desktop environment's own tooltip interface, for consistency with the rest of the desktop. The desktop will render the tooltip in its own style with its own fonts, which likely won't match the fonts the browser is using. The browser can often render text using a wider range of fonts than the desktop will.

Font support for U+2600 Black Sun With Rays isn't brilliant, so that makes it dicey to use especially in a tooltip. It renders OK for me (on Ubuntu/Chrome) but the desktop Windows desktop font Segoe UI doesn't support it.

A workaround would be to use one of the many JavaScript tooltip replacement scripts. These take over `title` attributes and convert them to hovering, positioned page elements when you mouse over them. They're then handled by the browser text renderer so you get the same fonts as the rest of the page and can apply CSS (eg to do font-face embedding).